# Differential geometry notion I can't find.

Tags: differential-geometry, parametrization, tangent-spaces

Suppose there are two orientable surfaces $M^1$ and $M^2$ with their respective gaussian maps $N^1$, $N^2$. Such that $p\in M^1\cap M^2$ is such that $T_pM^1=T_pM^2$ and $N^1(p)=N^2(p)$.

Let $h^1,h^2$ be **the local parameterizations by the tangent plane of $S^1$ and $S^2$** respectively, defined in the same neighbourhood of $p$ in the affine tangent plane $P$.

We say that $S^1$ is **locally inside** of $S^2$ in a neighbourhood $U\subset P$ of $p$ if we have that $h^1\geq h^2$.

I have the following questions:

- What does it mean to be a local parameterization by the tangent plane of $S^1$?
- In the definition of locally inside what does it mean for $h^1\geq h^2$?

From the definition of locally inside I would assume that $h^i$ would have to be a map into $\mathbb{R}$ but then it wouldn't be a parametrization of a surface nor a plane.

This problem comes from an exercises in my independent studies. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $h^i$ are real-valued. We’re writing the surfaces as graphs over the tangent plane.

Comment: Could you expand on this?

Comment: If you take $\vec x\in T_pM^1=T_pM^2$, $h^1(\vec x)$ is the height of $M^1$ over $\vec x$ and $h^2(\vec x)$ is the height of $M^2$ over $\vec x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't know if I understand, are you saying that $h^1$ is such that $(x,y,h^1(x,y)$) is a local parameterization for some $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in M^1$?

Comment: Yes, in a neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok that makes a lot more sense, if you copy those comments into an answer I can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're parametrizing the surfaces as graphs over the (common) tangent plane $T_pM^1=T_pM^2$. That is, in a neighborhood of $p$, both surfaces are parametrized by a neighborhood $U$ of the origin in $T_pM$, with $M^i$ being given locally as $\{(\vec u, h^i(\vec u)): \vec u\in U\}$. (Here we use a new coordinate system adapted to the geometry — namely, coordinates in $T_pM$ and a third coordinate orthogonal to the plane.)